# xpath to find non-empty links

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I want to use xPath to find links on a page, but only the ones with actual content:

So I do want to find: `<a href='test.html'><img src='test.jpg'></a>`

And `<a href='test.html'>link</a>`

But not: `<a href='test.html'></a>`

So far I tried: `//a[text()]` which finds the 2nd link in the example and skips the last one, but it also doesn't find the first one... I want to find that first one as well. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```xml
//a[text() or *]
```

That should get you all `<a>` elements with at least one child node (including text).

Demo ~ http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/0971a775fc7ac19b5b631a760c4aba9d

This is a great cheat-sheet for XPath expressions ~ https://devhints.io/xpath

Comment: I was checking your first answer, just `*` doesn't work indeed, text() or * is the best option and does exactly what I want

Comment: @patrick Yes, I found that myself while preparing a demo. I've also included some other child elements like `<span>` to show that it works with anything

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this

```
//a[text() or img]
```

to find all links with text or images(`img` tags).

Comment: nice! useful answer too. I went with Phil's solution since it also works when there are elements other than images in the link.